# How to dynamically change values in weblogic.xml?

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, jsessionid

I'd like to use values from a properties file (or some other filesystem resource) in my weblogic.xml. For example, I have this section:

```
<session-descriptor>
    <cookie-name>JSESSIONID</cookie-name>
    <cookie-domain>${my.domain}</cookie-domain>
</session-descriptor>
```

I then have a properties file specifying the value:

my.domain=qa.mydomain.com

on the file system specifying the domain.

Is this possible? Many other configuration mechanisms allow for this. The motivation is that the same code could be deployed in multiple environments with multiple domains and weblogic could simply take the appropriate domain from the file without any operator intervention.

Running weblogic 12c here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achieved using maven's resource plugin, assuming you already on mvn build.

You just need to add below configuration under `<build>` section

```
<resources>
  <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

You can add below property in your main pom in respective profiles:

```
<my.domain>desiredValue</my.domain>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it doesn't quite suit our needs. That would require rebuilding the WAR (EAR actually in this case) for every environment. I'm looking for a way to provide one artifact for all environments.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what you need is to use Weblogic's Deployment Plan feature.

I'm not so familar with it (never used it in productive environments) but with a deployment plan you should be able to change values in web.xml/weblogic.xml during deployment time.

Docs/Example:

- [Oracle Help Center - Creating and Using a Deployment Plan](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/12_2_1/01-27-001-CreatingandUsingDeploymentPlan/CreatingandUsingDeploymentPlan.html)
- [Oracle Docs - Save Deployment Plan](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WLACH/pagehelp/J2EEappsaveplantitle.html)
- [Example from middlewaremagic.com](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=5144)